# Bootstrap-select keydown is not working when livesearch is false

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-select

Hi I am using thirdparty js bootstrap-select to show custom select dropdown. To hide livesearch input for options below 5 I set liveSearch false in bootstrap-select. When livesearch is false when i trie to scroll down the options by pressing downkey in keyboard it shows error in the below line.

```
  if (that.options.liveSearch) $parent = $this.parent().parent();
```

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPBNU.png)

Comment: Post the source code and tell us your goal

Comment: are you talking about bootstrap dropdown ?????  please elaborate

Comment: Yes. Am using bootstrap-select.js to show custom select dropdrown.My goal is to show livesearch input box in select drodown when i have option list greater than 5. Hence to achieve this I have set liveSearch attribute of seect dropdown to false. In this case when I press keydown in keyboard in options it shows options is undefined in this part of code in bootstrap-select.js ' if (that.options.liveSearch) $parent = $this.parent().parent();'

Answer (score 0):

are you talking about bootstarp dropdown this code may help you:

```
 <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```